# AEM page move fails in instance, and also creating lot of versions

Tags: aem

We have created a launcher which will trigger the workflow on change. Workflow consist of OOTB page version creation.

So I have created a launcher on cq:Page modification event. with below properties

Event : Modified
Node : cq:Page
Path : /content
excludedList : event-user-data:changedByWorkflowProcess

But move operation fails when we perform move operation as move operation also contains one step which creates versions.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: AEM version? Have you modified the workflow?